# In a hexagon graph, how do I store 3D coordinates as an index for a 1D container / retrieve an element from a 1D container using 3D coordinates?

Tags: c++, containers, coordinates

I'm trying to store a graph of hexagons using cubical coordinates as detailed at https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates

I want to use a vector or some easily iteratable container to store Hex objects, basically collections of 3D integer coordinates plus a vector containing indexes of adjacent Hexes.

My problem is that I am having trouble coming up with functions to convert cubical X/Y/Z coordinates (which allows for negative integer values) into corresponding 1D container indices. Given any valid set of coordinates, I want to be able to get the particular index number of the hex.

I am aware of a function that works like

1D_index = f(x,y,z) = x + (max_width)*y + (max_width)(max_height)*z,

for an Cartesian grid, but I am having trouble producing a similar function for in hexagon space:

[image: Hexagon grid]

My Hex class and container is as such:

```
class Hex
{
private:
    int xCell, yCell, zCell;
    std::vector<int>neighbours;

public:
    Hex();
    Hex(int x, int y, int z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z);
    ~Hex();
};


std::vector<Hex*>hexGraph;
```

To populate the graph with unconnected nodes, I am using just listing all the coordinates that can exist, given the graph's positive and negative x/y/z dimensions:

```
for(int x = effectiveWorldNegX; x < effectiveWorldPosX; x++)
        for(int y = effectiveWorldPosY; y > effectiveWorldNegY; y--)
            hexGraph.push_back(new Hex(x,y,(x*-1)-y)); // x+y+z=0, so z=(-x-y)
```

Now here is where I am stumped. I want to connect the nodes using a loop like this:

```
for(std::vector<Hex*>iterator it = hexGraph.begin(); it != hexGraph.end(); ++it)
{
(*it)->neighbours.push_back( /* Index of upper left hex node */ )
(*it)->neighbours.push_back( /* Index of upper center hex node */ )
(*it)->neighbours.push_back( /* Index of upper right hex node */ )
...

}
```

And so on, but in order to do so, I need a way to find the index of, say, any cell +1x, -1y, +0z.

From the loop above, all I have determined is
1) the exact order that the Hexes are pushed back into the hexGraph vector, given the start/end of my loops

2) I may or may not need to offset all coordinate values by the negative X/Y/Z's distance from 0 to remove negatives

but where can I go from here?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving the issue is to give an `id` to every Vertex of the graph and then reference neighbour vertices by id's.

Example

```
using VertexId = size_t;

class Hex {
    std::vector<VertexId>neighbours;
  public:
    Hex(int x, int y, int z);
};

class VertexStorage {    
    std::unordered_map<VertexId, Hex> _id_to_hex;
    std::unordered_map<Hex, VertexId> _hex_to_id;
  public:
    // check if hex is in storage, return id
    // if not, assign new id an push tostorage
    // id could be increasing counter
    VertexId getId(const Hex &hex);
    Hex getHex(VertexId id);
};
```